# javascript/jquery mutate and append html in var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a simple array like this:

```
var arr = ['string_1', 'string_2'];
```

And I got the following html (simplified, but original is very large):

```
var html = '<div><input class="myInput" type="text"></div>'
```

I need to append to `#main_div` in my DOM this `html` variable, but filled with values from `arr`, so in this case there should be 2 inputs, filled with `string_1` and `string_2`.

I tried the following code:

```
$.each(arr, function(k, v){
          $(html).find('.myInput').val(v);
          $('#main_div').append(html);//mutated html var should be here
       });
```

but I get 2 empty inputs. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you

Comment: $.each(arr, function(k, v){
          $(html).find('.myInput').val(v)
var input= $('<div/>',{type:'text', class:'myinput',value:v});

          $('#main_div').append(input );//mutated html var should be here
       });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is almost there, but the problem is that you're not storing the jQuery object that you create from the `html` string, so you just append the unchanged original value. Try this:

```js
var arr = ['string_1', 'string_2'];
var html = '<div><input class="myInput" type="text"></div>'

$.each(arr, function(i, v) {
  var $html = $(html).find('.myInput').val(v).end();
  $('#main_div').append($html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_div"></div>
```

Note the use of `end()` which returns the originally selected element (the outer `div` from the `html` string in this case) instead of the `.myInput` element resulting from the `find()` call.

Finally, you need to give the `input` elements `name` attributes to ensure they are still valid HTML.

Comment: Thank you, works as expected. Is it possible to do the same without this temporary `$html` var, i.e. to make changes directly in original `html` var?

Comment: It's possible, but hacking around HTML as a string isn't a good idea when avoidable.